# Problems with custom activity hosted on AWS server

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom, appcenter

We have created a custom activity which initially was hosted on Heroku. Everything was working as intended until we move the files to AWS server. The server seems to be meeting the tech requirements also the change was reflected in config.json file and app centre. Despite this, every time I try to activate the journey now I receive the following errors:

2 errors. Resolve errors in the canvas before testing or activation:

- InteractionStudio RestActivity failed validation for { "url": "https://exacttarget-customactivity.spotcap.com/public/jb/activities/send-to-zapier/save/", "verb": "POST", "body": "", "useJwt": false }
- InteractionStudio RestActivity failed validation for { "url": "https://exacttarget-customactivity.spotcap.com/public/jb/activities/send-to-zapier/publish/", "body": "", "verb": "POST", "useJwt": false }

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Does your instance have SSL enabled on port 43?

Comment: You also need to ensure the routes in app exchange reflect this change. I suspect that might be the issue

Comment: Hey @Data_Kid - yes,  the SSL is enabled for this particular port. But not sure what you mean by "ensure the routes in app exchange reflect the change". I have swapped the links so now custom activity is pointing to AWS version. Anything else coming to your mind?

Comment: What was your solution at the end ?